# How to obtain an analytical solution of this system of coupled polynomial ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The coupled differential equations are of the following form

$$\begin{aligned} C_2 \dfrac{du(y)}{dy} &= v(y) + C_{1} v(y)^3 \\ \dfrac{dv(y)}{dy} + C_3 u(y) &= C_4\end{aligned}$$

where the boundary and symmetry conditions are $u(\pm H)=0$ and $v(0)=0$.

These equations represent flow of a non-Newtonian fluid under special conditions.

Comment: $u=v=0$ is a solution, do you have reason to suspect that other solutions exist? And why this complicated form for a first order system for $v''+av+bv^3=0$?

Comment: I am pretty sure other non-trivial solutions exist, as these equations represent flow of a non-Newtonian fluid under special conditions.